# Stop listening or remove event for Image() object onload event

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling

i have made a canvas which will stitch lots of small images to form one big image.

i have written it to listen an event which is one single image object loaded , then draw it into canvas , after load next image which will trigger the event again, it will stop this recursion by user specified number.

So after the user specified number has reached , i want to stop listening to the "load" event for my image object , how make my image object (which is "img") to stop listening the event "load"?

// Debug here

Webpage : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2321732/stitch_images/index.html

Javascript : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2321732/stitch_images/script/main.js

//for convenient editing

JSBin : http://jsbin.com/acakif/1/

NOTE : how i know the event is still going

1.Go to web inspector , javascript console

2.
  `img.src = "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2321732/stitch_images/images/0_3.jpg"`

3.
 it should NOT log "something has loaded"

Comment: Typing path to your localhost ;) will not work.

Comment: i dont understand , can describe more about it?

Comment: If I want it to run in it my browser (on my computer) there is no path like this "file://localhost/Users/kentliau/Desktop/stitch_images/images/0_3.jpg".

Comment: oh sorry , it is the debugging code , i have changed , the live version is okay by the way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code I see:

`img.addEventListener("load", drawStitch, true);`

However You remove the listener like this:

`img.removeEventListener("load", drawStitch);`

To put it simply if You want to remove a listener You have to pass all the arguments You passed to `addEventListener` to `removeEventListener`.

So in your example something like that:

`img.removeEventListener("load", drawStitch, true);`

I've tested it in Firefox/Firebug and step.2 no longer fires the event :)

Comment: he doesn't even need to remove the eventlistener, look at the code. What he wants is to stop loading the images.

Comment: From what I see Kent wants to prevent manual firing of the event. Images stopped loading in jsbin example...

Comment: omg , it so simple, yours stop listen the event , thanks

Comment: Hi @op1ekun is it correct, can i remove a listener from the object from within the onload listener? Like result_image.addEventListener('load',function(events){result_image.removeEventListener('load',function(events){console.log(events)}, false)}, false);

Comment: I require to do this, in case of multiple assignments, it every times initiates a new listener, the onload listener

Comment: Or simply a solution to http://jsfiddle.net/nithin_krishnan/z8urb5cd/

Comment: @Kailas Hey. I would just create a wrapper function that will remove it if it already exists and then attach again. Moreover you can create the listener  in the same wrapper function to have it in the scope when you want to remove it. No passing around required. Of course this is just an idea. Generally I like to decouple and abstract things like that, and removing listener doesn't appeal to me like a job for the listener itself. It's not DOM, right ;) ?

Comment: It is... DOM... :(... hidden DOM element..

Comment: @Kailas What I meant is that you shouldn't create constructs similar to element.parentNode.removeChild(element) when it comes to listeners. I can't promise anything, but I will try to create a simple fiddle to describe my idea. Cheers!